# Can I measure the molarity of Acetic Acid titrating Vineger with Sodium Hydroxide?

Tags: titration

Imagine I have 5 g of vineger which I titrated with 33 mL of 0.1M Sodium Hydroxide (NaOH).

I tried V₁S₁=V₂S₂ formula but It needs the volume of the acid.

I have tried to calculate the volume with W=SVM/1000 formula which gives me 250/3S mL (where S is the molarity of Acetic Acid), but at the end S is cancelled out.

Is there any way I can calculate the molarity of Acetic Acid?

Comment: You were able to weight 5 g in a container.  Maybe you still have some of the vinegar, may record the weight of an empty graduated cylinder (as $m_0$).  Then fill this cylinder again until it contains again 5 g (as $m_1 = m_0 + \pu{5 g}$) and read the volume of the vinegar at the wall of the graduated cylinder.  The density should be somewhere between 1.00 and 1.30 g/cm³ ([reference](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/density-aqueous-solution-formic-lactic-oxalic-acetic-citric-acid-concentration-d_1953.html), acetic acid).

Comment: According to the Handbook of Physics and Chemistry, the density of vinegar ($6$% $\ce{CH3COOH}$) is $1.0069 g/mL$ at $20°C$. So you can solve your problem  yourself.

Comment: @Maurice with the precision shown on the numeric values, I believe we can just write $1.0 g/mL$

Comment: @Nicolas Yes we can !

Comment: Is there a good reason for deviating from standard variables' symbols for molarity $(c→S)$ and volume $(V→W)$? $S$ is entropy and $W$ is work, so one would have to bend their mind trying to read your formulas. Kinda reminds me of this episode of [Andrew Dotson — Physics Professors Be Like (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/OcAXw6j7cdE?t=118).

Comment: Typically in such a situation the liquid wouldn't be weighed but rather dispensed with a volumetric pipette. Conversely if the liquid was weighed, then you might calculate the mass percentage of acetic acid. It is really an odd technique to measure a mass and then convert that to a volume.

Answer (score 2):

To use the formula that you indicate ($V_1 * C_1 = V_2 * C_2$), it is therefore necessary to know the volume of acetic acid $V_1$ or you only have the mass $m_1$.
To switch from one to the other, you need to know / determine the density of the acetic acid used : you just need to take a volume $V$ of acetic acid and weigh it, the ratio $\frac{m}{V}$ corresponds to the density $\rho_1$ -> by transferring into the dosage equation you thus arrive at $\frac {m_1}{\rho_1} C_1 = V_2 * C_2$, you know everything except $C_1$ so you can determine the concentration

Comment: Actually it should be $\frac {m_1} {\rho_1}$ to get volume.

Comment: Of course, I didn't read it well. So I modify with the correct formula. Thank you @MaxW for the vigilance